# Sucessive .setTimeouts jumping intermediate instances of .setTimeouts when setting element's text multiple times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to change an element's text successively with an interval of 1 second between each change.

The problem is that it is jumping the intermediate changes and just displaying the change from the element's initial text to the final text ('text' to 'text4' as opposed to: 'text' to 'text2' to 'text3' to 'text4').

Why is this happening and how can it be avoided?

```
setTimeout(
function() 
{
  $("#elementid").text("text2");
}, 1000);


setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    $("#elementid").text("text3");
  }, 1000);  


  setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    $("#elementid").text("text4");
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're setting all the timeouts at once, to complete after the second you set them. You change the delays to 1000, 2000, 3000:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $("#elementid").text("text2");
    }, 1000);


setTimeout(
    function() {
        $("#elementid").text("text3");
    }, 2000);


setTimeout(
    function() {
        $("#elementid").text("text4");
    }, 3000);
```

or nest them:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $("#elementid").text("text2");
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                $("#elementid").text("text3");
                setTimeout(
                    function() {
                        $("#elementid").text("text4");
                    }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) then I would suggest this snippet

```js
const showTextWithDelay = (text, delay) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
         $("#elementid").text(text);
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    })
};

showTextWithDelay("text1", 1000)
    .then(() => showTextWithDelay("text2", 1000))
    .then(() => showTextWithDelay("text3", 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elementid">---</div>
```